# JPA selecting, what should be lazy loaded, when not necessary

Tags: sql, performance, select, jpa, lazy-loading

i have a table mapped to this class:

```
@Entity(name = "status_history")
    @Table
    public class StatusChange implements Comparable<StatusChange> {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "when_")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date when;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ordering_id")
    private Ordering ordering;
    private Short status;
    ...



@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return id.intValue();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof StatusChange) {
        StatusChange sc = (StatusChange) o;
        if (id == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return id.equals(sc.getId());
    }
    return false;
}
    ...
```

which has 5006 rows. Why logging shows, that when i execute this query:

```
 Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT sh FROM status_history sh");
 return query.getResultList();
```

the logging shows JPA is fetching also the realted classes:

```
[EL Fine]: sql: 2013-08-09 17:02:52.631--ServerSession(27039955)--Connection(12972016)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--SELECT ID, TYPE, anniversary_newspapers, anniversary_newspapers_type, AUTHOR, copy_color, copy_format, decorated_folder, decorated_folder_note, delivery_type, publishing_description, SIGNATURE, TITLE, USAGE, work_amount, work_amount_desc, work_type, year_, BARCODE, comment_, denial_reason, EXHIBITION, exhibition_name, further_processing, LZA, no_new_scans, ONLINE, RESTORATION, SMALL, URGENT FROM ordered_object WHERE (ID = ?)
    bind => [54]
[EL Fine]: sql: 2013-08-09 17:02:52.632--ServerSession(27039955)--Connection(12972016)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--SELECT ID, TYPE, cancel_comment, claim_comment, COMMUNICATION, EDITOR, internal_id, LOCATION, STATUS, YEAR, yearly_number, billing_contact_id, oo_id, orderer_id, accumulated, customer_created, estimated_price, no_barcode, no_object, accumulated_id FROM ORDERING WHERE (oo_id = ?)
    bind => [54]
[EL Fine]: sql: 2013-08-09 17:02:52.634--ServerSession(27039955)--Connection(12972016)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--SELECT ID, _comment, control_finished, CONTROLLER, date_of_entry, empty_pages, scan_finished, scan_method1, scan_method2, scan_operator, SCANNER, SENDER, thumbnail_number, total_pages, oo_id FROM SCAN_INFO WHERE (oo_id = ?)
    bind => [54]
[EL Fine]: sql: 2013-08-09 17:02:52.635--ServerSession(27039955)--Connection(12972016)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--SELECT ID, onb_employee, contact_id FROM ORDERER WHERE (ID = ?)
    bind => [54]
```

and the query takes 30sec. What am i missing here?
thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

EclipseLink requires weaving be enabled to allow lazy to be used on OneToOne and ManyToOne relationships, otherwise it is just a hint
The document http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/concepts/app_dev007.htm has information on weaving with EclipseLink and links on how to set it up if it is not being used.
This is automatic in JPA-compliant app servers, and so usually overlooked in demos and tutorials.

You can also use joining or batch reading to speed up associated reference lookups, but might not be necessary with weaving and lazy relationships.  http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/QueryOptimization

Comment: yes, i figured it meanwhile. sorry, for bothering and thank for the reply!